# Is there a serializable generic Key/Value pair class in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking for a key/value pair object that I can include in a web service.

I tried using .NET's [`System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx) class, but it does not properly serialize in a web service. In a web service, the Key and Value properties are not serialized, making this class useless, unless someone knows a way to fix this.

Is there any other generic class that can be used for this situation?

I'd use .NET's [`System.Web.UI.Pair`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pair.aspx) class, but it uses Object for its types. It would be nice to use a Generic class, if only for type safety.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Just define a struct/class.

```
[Serializable]
public struct KeyValuePair<K,V>
{
  public K Key {get;set;}
  public V Value {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: @Paddy: Knowing how valuetypes gets hashed and comparing equality is a must

Comment: IDictionary is serializable now, in 4.5 (at least with JSON)

Comment: @Joe: Feel free to write your own constructor.

Comment: @leppie I did, but just an observation on this otherwise great answer.

Comment: After trying this, I am getting this build error. Please provide any ideas to fix. `'AttributeCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Where<KeyValuePair<string, object>>(IQueryable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>, Expression<Func<KeyValuePair<string, object>, bool>>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>'`

Answer (score 22):

I don't think there is as `Dictionary<>` itself isn't XML serializable, when I had need to send a dictionary object via a web service I ended up wrapping the `Dictionary<>` object myself and adding support for `IXMLSerializable`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents an XML serializable collection of keys and values.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the keys in the dictionary.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TValue">The type of the values in the dictionary.</typeparam>
[XmlRoot("dictionary")]
public class SerializableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>, IXmlSerializable
{
    #region Constants

    /// <summary>
    /// The default XML tag name for an item.
    /// </summary>
    private const string DEFAULT_ITEM_TAG = "Item";

    /// <summary>
    /// The default XML tag name for a key.
    /// </summary>
    private const string DEFAULT_KEY_TAG = "Key";

    /// <summary>
    /// The default XML tag name for a value.
    /// </summary>
    private const string DEFAULT_VALUE_TAG = "Value";

    #endregion

    #region Protected Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the XML tag name for an item.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual string ItemTagName
    {
        get
        {
            return DEFAULT_ITEM_TAG;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the XML tag name for a key.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual string KeyTagName
    {
        get
        {
            return DEFAULT_KEY_TAG;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the XML tag name for a value.
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual string ValueTagName
    {
        get
        {
            return DEFAULT_VALUE_TAG;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the XML schema for the XML serialization.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An XML schema for the serialized object.</returns>
    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes the object from XML.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reader">The XML representation of the object.</param>
    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        XmlSerializer keySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TKey));
        XmlSerializer valueSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TValue));

        bool wasEmpty = reader.IsEmptyElement;

        reader.Read();

        if (wasEmpty)
        {
            return;
        }

        while (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
        {
            reader.ReadStartElement(ItemTagName);

            reader.ReadStartElement(KeyTagName);
            TKey key = (TKey)keySerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.ReadEndElement();

            reader.ReadStartElement(ValueTagName);
            TValue value = (TValue)valueSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.ReadEndElement();

            this.Add(key, value);

            reader.ReadEndElement();
            reader.MoveToContent();
        }

        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes this instance to XML.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer">The writer to serialize to.</param>
    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        XmlSerializer keySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TKey));
        XmlSerializer valueSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TValue));

        foreach (TKey key in this.Keys)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement(ItemTagName);

            writer.WriteStartElement(KeyTagName);
            keySerializer.Serialize(writer, key);
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteStartElement(ValueTagName);
            TValue value = this[key];
            valueSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
            writer.WriteEndElement();

            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't mention Dictionary at all. The question is about serializing a key/value pair. Your answer is related, but I think it detracts from the fundamental issue.

Answer (score 17):

You will find the reason why KeyValuePairs cannot be serialised at this [MSDN Blog Post](http://blogs.msdn.com/seshadripv/archive/2005/11/02/488273.aspx)

The Struct answer is the simplest solution, however not the only solution.  A "better" solution is to write a Custom KeyValurPair class which is Serializable.

Comment: Note that the DataContractSerializer (as it comes with .NET 3.0 and WCF) can perfectly handle KeyValuePair<,>.  So it is not a general serialization issue, but rather an issue of the specific serializer you use (as the link to the MSDN Page suggests).

Comment: Your MSDN Blog Post (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seshadripv/archive/2005/11/02/488273.aspx) is now a dead link

Answer (score 8):

```
 [Serializable]
 public class SerializableKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>
    {

        public SerializableKeyValuePair()
        {
        }

        public SerializableKeyValuePair(TKey key, TValue value)
        {
            Key = key;
            Value = value;
        }

        public TKey Key { get; set; }
        public TValue Value { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In the 4.0 Framework, there is also the addition of the Tuple family of classes that are serializable and equatable. You can use `Tuple.Create(a, b)` or `new Tuple<T1, T2>(a, b)`.

Comment: While the Tuple types are Serializable, they are unfortunately not XML Serializable

Answer (score 0):

A KeyedCollection is a type of dictionary that can be directly serialized to xml without any nonsense.  The only issue is that you have to access values by: coll["key"].Value;

Comment: I don't think that KeyedCollection can be serialized within a **WebService** because it does not have any public constructor. The [Serializable]-attribute does only work for remoting.

Answer (score 0):

**XmlSerializer doesn't work with Dictionaries. Oh, and it has problems with KeyValuePairs too**

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/314447/XmlSerializer-doesnt-work-with-Dictionaries-Oh-and

Answer (score 0):

Use the DataContractSerializer since it can handle the Key Value Pair.

```
    public static string GetXMLStringFromDataContract(object contractEntity)
    {
        using (System.IO.MemoryStream writer = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            var dataContractSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(contractEntity.GetType());
            dataContractSerializer.WriteObject(writer, contractEntity);
            writer.Position = 0;
            var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(writer);
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataTable` is my favorite collection for (solely) wrapping data to be serialized to JSON, since it's easy to expand without the need for an extra `struct` & acts like a serializable replacement for `Tuple<>[]`

Maybe not the cleanest way, but I prefer to include & use it directly in the classes (which shall be serialized), instead of declaring a new `struct`

```
class AnyClassToBeSerialized
{
    public DataTable KeyValuePairs { get; }

    public AnyClassToBeSerialized
    {
        KeyValuePairs = new DataTable();
        KeyValuePairs.Columns.Add("Key", typeof(string));
        KeyValuePairs.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
    }

    public void AddEntry(string key, string value)
    {
        DataRow row = KeyValuePairs.NewRow();
        row["Key"] = key; // "Key" & "Value" used only for example
        row["Value"] = value;
        KeyValuePairs.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use `Tuple<string,object>`

see this for more details on `Tuple` usage : [Working with Tuple in C# 4.0](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/11/working-with-tuple-in-c-40.html)

Comment: This was [already suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83232/is-there-a-serializable-generic-key-value-pair-class-in-net/4598558#4598558). Unfortunately, the Tuple class is not XML Serializable.