# Is it possible to deserialize JSON to List<MyObject<T,K>> with JSON.Net

Tags: c#, generics, serialization, json.net

I have a class:

```
[Serializable]
    public class KVPair<TKey, TValue>
    {
        public TKey Key { get; set; }
        public TValue Value { get; set; }

        public KVPair(TKey k, TValue v)
        {
            Key = k;
            Value = v;
        }
    }
```

that I create:

```
List<KVPair<string,string>> kvPairs;
```

Using the JSON.Net library I can serialize the list and yield:

```
"[{\"Key\":\"Two\",\"Value\":\"2\"},{\"Key\":\"One\",\"Value\":\"1\"}]"
```

When I de-serialize this string back to List> I get the correct count of objects but they are null.  Any suggestions would be great help.

Comment: You know there's already a KeyValuePair<K,V> type?

Comment: Check this SO question out as there are issues serializing the KeyValuePair with webservices:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83232/is-there-a-serializable-generic-key-value-pair-class-in-net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that you might need to add a parameterless constructor:

```
public KVPair() {
}
```

Perhaps JSON.net doesn't know how to construct your object so it silently fails.