# Web Service: Want to Return Serializable Dictionary But It Shows DataSet

Tags: c#, web-services, serialization, dictionary

I want to return the Dictionary collection from the webservice.  Since we could not directly return Dictionary Type from the webservice, I made the Serializable Dictionary as described in  [this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2006/05/03/444961.aspx)

It is fine and I could return the collection as xml below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SerializableDictionaryOfStringString xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <Item>
    <Key>
      <string xmlns="">k1</string>
    </Key>
    <Value>
      <string xmlns="">abcdef</string>
    </Value>

  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Key>
      <string xmlns="">k2</string>
    </Key>
    <Value>
      <string xmlns="">xyz</string>
    </Value>

  </Item>
</SerializableDictionaryOfStringString>
```

However, the problem occurs when consuming this webservice.  Instead of the SerializableDictionary Return Type, my web service method shows the return data type as DataSet.  I don't know how to handle the return data and utilize because although it returns as the Dataset, it is not actually the dataset and I could not do anything with it such as bind to gridview, ds.tables[0], etc....

So, how can I manipulate the return data from the webservice?

Comment: OK, what libs are you using, what version(s) etc. And are you handcrafting that XML?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A dictionary is not the most logical choice for a DTO (Data Transfer Object).

Take a step back, what do you want to return from Server to Consumer?

I think it is just

```
class MyDTO { public string Key {get; set; } public string Value {get; set; } }

public List<MyDTO> Servermethod() { ... }
```

Add the `[WebMethod]` , `[Serializable]` or `[OperationContract]` , `[DataContract]` attributes as necessary.

And then it is up to the Client to create a Dictionary from the List is that's convenient.

Comment: Indeed, also see the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83232/is-there-a-serializable-generic-key-value-pair-class-in-net

Comment: yes @Henk you got my vote.  that's crystal clear.  and it is really easy to go to and from a Dictionary using linq.