# Looking for a CSLA datastructure like a Tuple

Tags: c#, data-structures, csla

I am working on a CSLA project right now and I am wondering if there is a data-structure similar to tuple that is Mobile.  I'm looking to use a `MobileList<Tuple<int, string>>` but I cannot because the Tuple is not Mobile.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need two parameters you could use [KeyValuePair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx)

UPDATE:

So as your comment implies, kvp cannot be serialized. You could use the approach from this question if you can live with adding a new type: [Is there a serializable generic Key/Value pair class in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83232/is-there-a-serializable-generic-key-value-pair-class-in-net)

Comment: When I use the `KeyValuePair<int, string>` it is not getting correctly serialized.  I am getting `<"", 0>` out.  It is getting correctly set though.