# Deserializing a List of KeyValuePairs

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have some XML in the following format:

```
<ObjectData>
  <ModelName>MODEL_123</ModelName>
  <ObjectName>OBJECT_A</ObjectName>
  <Values>
    <KeyValuePair>
      <Key>NAME</Key>
      <Value>PAUL</Value>
    </KeyValuePair>
    ...
  </Values>
</ObjectData>
...
```

I want to deserialize this into the following class:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "")]
public class ObjectData
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
    public string ObjectName { get; set; }
    [XmlArray]
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Values { get; set; }
}
```

When I use this code, the `KeyValuePair`s are not deserialized and the Values property is empty.

```
List<ObjectData> data = new List<ObjectData>();
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObjectData));

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(inputXML)))
{             
    reader.MoveToContent();
    ObjectData temp = (ObjectData)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    data.Add(temp);
}
```

Is the `KeyValuePair` class not serializable in the way I use it?  Or is there a problem in my `ObjectData` class?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what tags are for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a serializable generic Key/Value pair class in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83232/is-there-a-serializable-generic-key-value-pair-class-in-net)

Comment: not really a duplicate.  That post did help reach the solution, but I had the second requirement of deserializing it into a List

Comment: @John I see your point, but I think it helps the titles get found later on in search engines

Comment: Actually, no, it doesn't help. The tags get into the SEO in any case.

Comment: Then I'm confused.  How does having a keyword in the h1 tag not help SEO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try specifying the element names in your attributes:

```
[XmlArray("Values")]
[XmlArrayItem("KeyValuePair")]
public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Values { get; set; }
```

Comment: This now gives me the correct Count of KeyValuePairs, but the Key and Value still show up empty.

Answer (score 2):

Combining D Stanley's answer with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83232/is-there-a-serializable-generic-key-value-pair-class-in-net), I was able to come up with the right structure:

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "")]
public class ObjectData
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
    public string ObjectName { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("Values")]
    [XmlArrayItem("KeyValuePair")] 
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Values { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class KeyValuePair<K, V> {
    public K Key { get; set; }
    public V Value { get; set; }
    public KeyValuePair() { }
    public KeyValuePair(K key, V value)
    {
        this.Key = key;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no setter for `Key` or `Value` in the [`KeyValuePair` struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx).  You'll have to change the data type.  You can decorate the property so you can name the new type whatever you want.

```
....
    [XmlArray("Values")]
    [XmlArrayItem("KeyValuePair")]  //not needed if MyItem is named KeyValuePair
    public List<MyItem> Values { get; set; }
}

public class MyItem
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I tried removing `[XmlArrayItem("KeyValuePair")]` as you suggest, but my List was coming up empty without it.

Comment: @Paul: Did you create a class named `KeyValuePair`?

Comment: Yes. `public class KeyValuePair<K, V> { ... }`

Comment: The example class wasn't generic.  The generic version would serialize as `KeyValuePairOfStringString` (or something like that...).