# Serializable key value pair or tuple in silverlight

Tags: .net, wcf, silverlight, serialization

I need to send a list of key value pairs or tuples to a silverlight application from WCF. I have found that the KeyValuePair class is not serializable and the tuples class is also not serializable in silverlight.

I read a blog post about this found here: http://davybrion.com/blog/2010/06/more-on-system-tuple-and-serializationdeserialization/

That also had some responses from other blogs. I went to one of them found here: http://www.devvblog.com/?p=5

But I don't really understand how to use it. I expected I could do `Tuple<double> temp = new Tuple();`. However, there doesn't seem to be a default constructor. If anyone knows how to use this, please explain. Otherwise, is there a way I can simply send a list of object pairs from WCF to a silverlight app?

Comment: You can't just send a list of objects across the wire and expect WCF to know how to deserialize them. It needs to know the type of the object before it can deserialize it. Not sure why you can't use the generic version of KeyValuePair, since it's marked as serializable in MSDN. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx

Comment: It isn't marked with that attribute under silverlight, though.

Comment: If that's the case, I tend to just roll my own. It's not difficult to implement the Serializable methods in your own list class.

Answer (score 1):

I favor the custom struct solution described in this similar question. Easy to use and easy to understand.

[Is there a serializable generic Key/Value pair class in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83232/is-there-a-serializable-generic-key-value-pair-class-in-net)

Comment: I initially tried that. When I added my service reference in silverlight, it was not using my shared struct between my service and the silverlight project. I have the "Reuse types in all referenced assemblies" checked and I had my other classes referenced correctly, but that struct was not.

Comment: Did you remember to mark the struct with [DataContract] and [DataMember]?

Comment: Yes, I did. I am wondering if the Template design of the class was breaking it.