# XML Serialization of member variable as xmlnode

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have some XML which I would like to serialize into a class.

```
<Group>
 <Employees>
     <Employee>
         <Name>Hari</Name>
         <Age>30</Age>
     </Employee>
     <Employee>
         <Name>Yougov</Name>
         <Age>31</Age>
     </Employee>
     <Employee>
         <Name>Adrian</Name>
         <Age>28</Age>
     </Employee>
</Employees >
```

The above XML can be realized in C# pretty much easily.
But I'm stumbled upon my requirement, where the XML looks like,

```
<Group>
 <Employees>
    <Hari Age=30 />
    <Yougov Age=31 />
    <Adrian Age=28 />
 </Employees >
</Group>
```

Where Employees is a `List<Employee>` with `KeyValuePair<string, int>("Hari", 30)`

How do I design the classes and member variables to get the above serialized XML?
(Provided, there wont be any duplicate names in the employee list)

Any help is much appreciated.

*[Serializing KeyValuePair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83232/is-there-a-serializable-generic-key-value-pair-class-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to use the data as the schema; in particular, an awful lot of names **are not valid** as xml element names, but also: it just isn't good practice (for example, it makes it virtually useless in terms of schema validation). If you want to be terse, maybe something like:

```
<Employees>
    <Add Name="Hari" Age="30" />
</Employees>
```

or

```
<Employees>
    <Employee Name="Hari" Age="30" />
</Employees>
```

which can be done simply with:

```
[XmlArray("Employees"), XmlArrayItem("Employee")]
public List<Employee> Employees {get;set;}
```

and:

```
public class Employee {
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name {get;set;}
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Age {get;set;}
}
```

`XmlSerializer` does not support the "content as an element name" serializer, unless you do everything yourself with `IXmlSerializable` ***from the parent element*** (it would have to be from the parent, as `XmlSerializer` would have no way of identifying the child to handle there).

Comment: Thanks Marc, the second option is what I'm actually using for now since it is less intruding my required schema. But there should be some way out there to achieve the result?

Comment: Well, regarding the validation, the "names" are just place holders for the question, the actual value is just alpha-numeric id[0-1 A-Z a-z] only. So that wont be a problem, also the id is unique and so it wint repeat in the same node. (if it is not, I'm doing something wrong in my validation or some one messed up my XML, which is entirely different case!)

Comment: @Aczire to repeat: `XmlSerializer` is not going to help you very much with what you are trying to do

Answer (score 3):

I would go with Linq2Xml in your case.

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(......);
var emps = xDoc.Descendants("Employees").Elements()
    .Select(x => new Employee() { 
                        Name = x.Name.ToString(), 
                        Age = int.Parse(x.Attribute("Age").Value) 
                    })
    .ToList();
```

PS: `Age=30` is not valid. It shoudl be `Age="30"`