# JSON representation of a list of keyvaluepairs

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have an MVC JSON controller method that I call from frontend. It looks like this:

`public JsonResult FacetedSearch(string searchString, List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> facets)`

I'm calling it via jQuery ajax at the frontend, I'm serializing the data in the following manner:

`JSON.stringify({searchString: "the matrix", facets: [{Key: "TypeName", Value: "Feature Film"}, {Key:"TypeName", Value:"Series"}]}`

When I debug through my application code, I see that searchString gets passed successfully over to the MVC method, but the variable `facets` gives me a list of 2 KeyValuePairs with null Key and Value.

I've looked at my serialization and it seems valid but for whatever reason it isn't going over to my application correctly. What gives?

Comment: You're passing everything to ASP as a single JSON object, but your method is expecting two parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than expect two objects in your signature, it would make more sense to expect a single object that contains both of your parameters.  This would be something like the following.

```
public JsonResult FacetedSearch(RequestObject requestObject)
{ }

public class RequestObject
{
    public string searchString { get; set; } 
    public List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> facets { get; set; }
}
```

This way, when you send your JSON object, the signature is an object with two properties, just like the object that you are sending.

Comment: @JaySun Instead of calling JSON.stringify, what happens if you build an object with your values?  Does it make it to your Controller at that point?

Comment: @JaySun It seems that there may be a way to do it with the Json.Net library.  However, in agreement with your post, it doesn't seem serializable by default

Answer (score 0):

Per [Is there a serializable generic Key/Value pair class in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83232/is-there-a-serializable-generic-key-value-pair-class-in-net)

I found out why it's not serializing it. Apparently it's unserializable.