# Wcf serialize IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Key, Value>> failed

Tags: .net, wcf, serialization

My code is like below:

```
// interfaces
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    MyResponse MyOperation(MyRequest request);
}

// services
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public MyResponse MyOperation(MyRequest request)
    {
        // do nothing.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

// request & data contracts
[DataContract]
public class MyRequest
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Enums, string>> Settings { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class MyResponse
{
    //...
}

[DataContract]
public enum Enums
{
    [EnumMember] E1,
    [EnumMember] E2
}
```

Error will occur when invoke "MyOperation".

Stack:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2146232828   Message=Exception has been thrown by the target
>   of an invocation.   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>          at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>          at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry
>   tme)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry
>   tme)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>          at Microsoft.Tools.TestClient.Program.Main(String[] args)   InnerException: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
>          HResult=-2146232828
>          Message=An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details.
>          Source=System
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
>               at System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
>               at Microsoft.Tools.TestClient.UI.MainForm.invokeServiceWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(Object
>   sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
>               at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnRunWorkerCompleted(RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs
>   e)
>               at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.AsyncOperationCompleted(Object
>   arg)
>          InnerException: System.ArgumentNullException
>               HResult=-2147467261
>               Message=Value cannot be null. Parameter name: elementType
>               Source=mscorlib
>               ParamName=elementType
>               StackTrace:
>                    at System.Array.CreateInstance(Type elementType, Int32 length)
>                    at Microsoft.Tools.TestClient.Variables.ArrayVariable.CreateObject()
>                    at Microsoft.Tools.TestClient.Variables.CompositeVariable.CreateObject()
>                    at Microsoft.Tools.TestClient.ServiceExecutor.BuildParameters(Variable[]
>   inputs)
>                    at Microsoft.Tools.TestClient.ServiceExecutor.PopulateInputParameters(String
>   methodName, Variable[] inputs, Type contractType, MethodInfo& method,
>   ParameterInfo[]& parameters, Object[]& parameterArray)
>                    at Microsoft.Tools.TestClient.ServiceExecutor.Execute(ServiceInvocationInputs
>   inputValues)
>                    at Microsoft.Tools.TestClient.ServiceExecutor.Execute(ServiceInvocationInputs
>   inputValues)
>                    at Microsoft.Tools.TestClient.ServiceExecutor.ExecuteInClientDomain(ServiceInvocationInputs
>   inputs)
>                    at Microsoft.Tools.TestClient.UI.MainForm.invokeServiceWorker_DoWork(Object
>   sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
>                    at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
>                    at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object
>   argument)
>               InnerException:

Answer (score 1):

WCF Services don't play nicely with `KeyValuePair`

This is presumably what's causing the error:

```
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Enums, string>> Settings { get; set; }
```

Make your own class for the KeyValuePair instead, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/83265/3033053).