# C# XPath cannot find any element

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xpath, soap

I am able to read XML from this service at localhost, and it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetEventsResponse
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <GetEventsResult
        xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Zadatak3.Models"
        xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <d2p1:Event>
            <d2p1:EndDate>2022-08-02T00:00:00</d2p1:EndDate>
            <d2p1:Id>1</d2p1:Id>
            <d2p1:Info></d2p1:Info>
            <d2p1:Name>Party u Močvari</d2p1:Name>
            <d2p1:Price>50</d2p1:Price>
            <d2p1:Promoter>Močvara Promotions</d2p1:Promoter>
            <d2p1:StartDate>2022-08-01T00:00:00</d2p1:StartDate>
            <d2p1:Type>Party</d2p1:Type>
            <d2p1:Url>http://mocvara.com/event/1</d2p1:Url>
            <d2p1:Venue>
                <d2p1:Address>Neka adresa</d2p1:Address>
                <d2p1:City>Zagreb</d2p1:City>
                <d2p1:ContactName>Pero</d2p1:ContactName>
                <d2p1:Country>Hrvatska</d2p1:Country>
                <d2p1:Id>1</d2p1:Id>
                <d2p1:Name>Močvara</d2p1:Name>
                <d2p1:PostalCode>10000</d2p1:PostalCode>
            </d2p1:Venue>
        </d2p1:Event>
        <d2p1:Event>
            <d2p1:EndDate>2022-08-11T00:00:00</d2p1:EndDate>
            <d2p1:Id>2</d2p1:Id>
            <d2p1:Info></d2p1:Info>
            <d2p1:Name>Koncert u Skwhatu</d2p1:Name>
            <d2p1:Price>80</d2p1:Price>
            <d2p1:Promoter>Kištra</d2p1:Promoter>
            <d2p1:StartDate>2022-08-10T00:00:00</d2p1:StartDate>
            <d2p1:Type>Koncert</d2p1:Type>
            <d2p1:Url>http://swkwhat.com/event/2</d2p1:Url>
            <d2p1:Venue>
                <d2p1:Address>Viktorovac 1</d2p1:Address>
                <d2p1:City>Sisak</d2p1:City>
                <d2p1:ContactName>Ivica</d2p1:ContactName>
                <d2p1:Country>Hrvatska</d2p1:Country>
                <d2p1:Id>2</d2p1:Id>
                <d2p1:Name>Skwhat</d2p1:Name>
                <d2p1:PostalCode>44000</d2p1:PostalCode>
            </d2p1:Venue>
        </d2p1:Event>
        <d2p1:Event>
            <d2p1:EndDate>2022-09-04T00:00:00</d2p1:EndDate>
            <d2p1:Id>3</d2p1:Id>
            <d2p1:Info></d2p1:Info>
            <d2p1:Name>Festival u Močvari</d2p1:Name>
            <d2p1:Price>220</d2p1:Price>
            <d2p1:Promoter>Čvarci</d2p1:Promoter>
            <d2p1:StartDate>2022-09-01T00:00:00</d2p1:StartDate>
            <d2p1:Type>Festival</d2p1:Type>
            <d2p1:Url>http://mocvara.com/festival/1</d2p1:Url>
            <d2p1:Venue>
                <d2p1:Address>Neka adresa</d2p1:Address>
                <d2p1:City>Zagreb</d2p1:City>
                <d2p1:ContactName>Pero</d2p1:ContactName>
                <d2p1:Country>Hrvatska</d2p1:Country>
                <d2p1:Id>1</d2p1:Id>
                <d2p1:Name>Močvara</d2p1:Name>
                <d2p1:PostalCode>10000</d2p1:PostalCode>
            </d2p1:Venue>
        </d2p1:Event>
    </GetEventsResult>
</GetEventsResponse>
```

This is the soap request that I'm sending and the app manages to read the query:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <s:Body>
        <SearchXmlResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <SearchXmlResult>/GetEventsResponse/GetEventsResult/d2p1:Event/d2p1:Name</SearchXmlResult>
        </SearchXmlResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But when I try to select single node, XPath returns nothing.

Code in the app looks like this:

```
public string SearchXml(string query)
{
    //

    //http://localhost:5068/EventService.asmx/

    //<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    //<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    //<soap:Body>
    //<SearchXml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    //<query>/GetEventsResponse/GetEventsResult/d2p1:Event[1]/d2p1:Name</query>
    //</SearchXml>
    //</soap:Body>
    //</soap:Envelope>

    const string serviceUrl = "http://localhost:5068/EventService.asmx/GetEvents";
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.Load(serviceUrl);

    var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(document.NameTable);

    nsmgr.AddNamespace("d2p1", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Zadatak3.Models");
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("i", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

    try
    {
        XmlNode? node = document.SelectSingleNode(query, nsmgr);
        if (node != null)
        {
            return node.InnerText;
        }
        else
        {
            return $"Data does not exist! Search term: {query}";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return $"{e.Message}";
        throw;
    }
}
```

I tried different queries, selecting multiple nodes, but it does not fetch any results

Comment: What your query? The `query` variable is not defined in your C# code.

Comment: edited again, i pasted whole method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here is that the top two elements are in a default namespace `xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"`:

```xml
<GetEventsResponse
    xmlns=""http://tempuri.org/"">
    <GetEventsResult>
        <!--Contents omitted -->
    </GetEventsResult>
</GetEventsResponse>
```

Which is semantically equivalent to e.g.:

```xml
<def:GetEventsResponse
    xmlns:def=""http://tempuri.org/"">
    <def:GetEventsResult>
        <!--Contents omitted -->
    </def:GetEventsResult>
</def:GetEventsResponse>
```

Thus you must add this default namespace into the `XmlNamespaceManager` **with some assigned prefix** in order to query for these nodes by qualified name.  Your caller may then use that assigned prefix in their query.

E.g. if you assign the prefix `tempuri` to `http://tempuri.org/`:

```
nsmgr.AddNamespace("tempuri", "http://tempuri.org/");
```

Then the following query by the caller will now work:

```
/tempuri:GetEventsResponse/tempuri:GetEventsResult/d2p1:Event/d2p1:Name
```

Alternatively, the caller's query could specify the namespace URI directly, rather than via some namespace prefix, by using the [`local-name()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-local-name) and [`namespace-uri()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-namespace-uri) XPath functions:

```
/*[local-name() = 'GetEventsResponse' and namespace-uri() = 'http://tempuri.org/']/*[local-name() = 'GetEventsResult' and namespace-uri() = 'http://tempuri.org/']/d2p1:Event/d2p1:Name
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sl0JOf).

Notes:

- Attempting to query a node in a default namespace without using prefix by adding the default namespace to the `XmlNamespaceManager` with an empty string `""` prefix  seems not to work.  Even if I do

  ```
   nsmgr.AddNamespace("", "http://tempuri.org/");
  ```

  Your initial query still fails.

  Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7fjLvp).
- You might want to reconsider your API design to allow the caller to specify the namespaces they want to query, e.g. by adding a `List<SerializableKeyValuePair<string, string>> namespaces` argument to your method, where `SerializableKeyValuePair` comes from e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/83232/3744182).  This makes it the responsibility of the caller to specify the namespaces correctly, rather that the responsibility of your your server-side app to hardcode all the necessary prefixes.